# How can I use a variable name in a Cucumber datatable in a step definition in Java?

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber, bdd

I have the following scenario in Cucumber:

```
Scenario: As sysadmin I delete an user used for testing

  Given I in selfservice at the page Manage user
  When I search for an existing user 

    | users | ORGADMINUSER_LASTNAME         |
    | users | ORGADMINUSER_LASTNAME         |
```

The string ORGADMINUSER_LASTNAME is a variable in my Java class which contains a value when executing the scenario. How can I convert this string to the value of the variable with that name?

This is the step definition in Java:

```
    @When("^I search for an existing user and delete it$")
    public void i_search_for_an_existing_user_and_delete_it(DataTable table) throws Throwable {

        // I get the list of users from the Data table and then pass them through the web elements in manage users

        Thread.sleep(5000);
         List<List<String>> user =table.raw();
         System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Number of users in Feature file: " + user.size());

        try{
         for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) { 

             List<String> org= user.get(i);

             String Userstring=user.get(i).get(1).toString();
             System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
             System.out.println(Userstring);
```

Comment: Use a getter to get the value of that variable?

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to simply check if the user value is `ORGADMINUSER_LASTNAME` and then simply make a get call to that variable and replace the `Userstring` with that variable.

Otherwise, if you want something more generic, you may want to look into the Reflection API. Something like:
`ClassOfTheField.getField(Userstring).get(null)`

Just make sure the Userstring field exists within `ClassOfTheField` using `getFields()` first, otherwise you'll get a `NoSuchFieldException` and that the field is static (or pass in an instance of the class if not inside the get call).